# Using Custom defined variables in PgAdmin III?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

First of all, thank you beforehand for helping me with this. Please do not state that this is a repeat question as I have searched a lot but still none of the threads I found here relate to my query. Actually I have a simple query which I'm failing to pass through and needed some help. My issue is as follows,

I want to run a simple SQL query to insert some data into a table i.e.,

```
INSERT INTO "public"."plan" (id,name,description) VALUES (6,"Plan Name","Plan Description");
```

But instead of passing **Plan Name** and **Plan Description** as text, I'm looking to define variables and pass those instead, in short something like this,

```
INSERT INTO "public"."plan" (id,name,description) VALUES (6,customPlanName,customPlanDescription);
```

I've tried using the following but this doesn't work,

```
DECLARE 
   planname TEXT;
   plandesc TEXT;
SET planname = 'MidasName';
SET plandesc = 'PlanDescription';
INSERT INTO "public"."plan" (id,name,description) VALUES (6,planname,plandesc);
```

Can you please help me out with this? I want something to be run using PostgreSQL on PgAdmin III

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: maybe prepared statements instead?.. `prepare st1 (text,int) as select $1, @4;execute st1 ('some text',3);`

Comment: Thanks Vao Tsun, if not a problem, can you give an example relating to my query up there.

Comment: pgAdmin III has a built-in scripting language called "pgScript" which might be what you're looking for: https://pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgscript.html Or possibly you want a simple user-defined function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html or a more complex plPGSQL one: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

Comment: I provided the example, but you probably are looking for pgScript as @IMSoP offers

Comment: @IMSoP ... I'll definitely give it a go and will update. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

example with prepared statements:

```
prepare plan_insert (text,text) 
  as INSERT INTO "public"."plan" (id,name,description) VALUES (6,$1,$2);
execute plan_insert ('MidasName','PlanDescription');
execute plan_insert ('Some Other','Some more');
```